# Magento 2: how to change the color of dots below product image gallery?

Tags: magento2, css, design

In the mobile view of product page (Blank theme) there are dots below the image gallery to indicate the active image.

I tried to changed the color of those dots (orange by default) in the file I use for my custom theme's customizations. However the dots classes are defined in a `gallery.css` file, I guess that's why the new values I set in my custom theme haven't been applied.

How can I override / extend the values from the `gallery.css` file?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override, copy `lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.less` to your theme: `theme_dir/web/mage/gallery/gallery.less`. Make the desired changes in this file. Now recompile less files by removing contents of `pub/static` and `var/view_preprocessed` and then flush cache and browser cache.